# Skip parts of the install msi install sequence

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have an msi installer that I made using wix toolset, the installer works fine but I need to be able to use the installer as a an updater also, so in my app I download the latest installer and invoke it, The problem is that the installer normally shows a "license dialog" and an "install directory dialog" I want to skip both dialogs and just supply the installer with the install location as a command line argument so the user only sees the installation progress bar with out going through the whole installation process with every update.

Please advise, and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could change the dialog order implementing a custom UI element where you then schedule your dialogs depending on a property.
See https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/user-interface/new-link-in-the-chain/ for a simple but complete example.

Comment: The tutorial you included adds "new dialog to collect registration information", I need to schedule a dialog that already exists (installation dialog), so could you provide a more specific example?

Comment: I think the tutorial provides everything you need. Just ignore the new dialog and concentrate at the <UI> definition at the end of the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

So for anyone having the same question, the msi has something called passive mode it only shows a progress bar

```
msiexec /i "C:\InstallLocation" /passive
```